# Closing a window and opening a new one via a button in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I was wondering if there was a way to open a new instance of Toplevel() and close the current one via the press of a button, i.e. close the current window and open a new one. Here is the code in question:

```
def start(self):
        self.name = tk.DoubleVar()
        name_w = tk.Toplevel(root)
        name_w.wm_title("Enter name")
        f1 = tk.Frame(name_w)
        f1.pack()
        L1 = tk.Label(f1, text="Please enter your name!")
        L1.grid(row=0, column=0)
        E1 = tk.Entry(f1, textvariable=self.name)
        E1.grid(row=1, column=0)
        N1 = tk.Button(f1, text="Next", command = self.Q1)
        N1.grid(row=2, column=0)
```

In this case, I want self.Q1 to be called, while also destroying name_w. Is there anyway to do this? Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean when you are closing the `name_w` you want `self.Q1` to be called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. To close an instance of `Toplevel` simply destroy it. You'll need to save a reference to the window. In your case I would either have `Q1` destroy the window, or make a separate function that calls `Q1` and then destroys the window. It all depends on what the main purpose of `Q1` is.

For example:

```
def start(self):
    ...
    self.new_window = name_w
    ...

def quit_window(self):
    self.Q1()
    self.new_window.destroy()
```

If you have multiple of these you might need to store the window references in a list or dictionary, but the basic mechanism is the same: use `.destroy()` to destroy the window.

This isn't the only way, of course. You could use lambda or `functools.partial` and a function that accepts the name of the window to destroy, or you could use nested functions, etc.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't really get this answer @Bryan. I want to close the main window and open a new one with a button but I don't get it. Does @F. Ashley has to define a function where self has two operations like in your answer? I also don't understand how he has to call the command. Is it `command=quit_window` in this case?